# How to connect to EWS API?

Tags: ms-office, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have found out that EWS API is authenticated from OAuth 2.0. I want to call the GetEvents API [1] of EWS. The hard part to understand is how to get the authorization from users for this action. Can someone point me out to the relevant docs on how to register an App and getting the client ID and secret for EWS.

[1] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566199(v=exchg.150)

Answer (score 0):

There is no MSDN documentation on the specifics for using OAuth with EWS at this time, although there is for the [O365 REST APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn605895(v=office.15).aspx). To register an app that uses Exchange Online, you'll have to follow the steps provided in the [Enabling Microsoft Azure portal access to manage applications using the OAuth2 protocol](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/04/07/enabling-microsoft-azure-portal-access-to-manage-applications-using-the-oauth2-protocol.aspx) blog post, but the rest of the steps for EWS (not REST) haven't been documented yet. I can update this post when that documentation has been written.